# How to concat each row found?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets formula that loads some data in each row for as many data as found

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INICIO!C4=AUX!Q2;AUX!Q3:Q10))
```

So if there are 6 items, for example, I get 6 rows with each item like this, which is correct:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
Item5
Item6
```

But now I need to concatenate each item found with some text, so I'm using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INICIO!C4=AUX!Q2;CONCATENATE(P2;Q2;"_";AUX!Q3:Q10)))
```

But this will concatenate the text to the first item and then show the rest of the items all in the same cell.

How can I edit the formula to get:

```
AABB_Item1
AABB_Item2
AABB_Item3
AABB_Item4
AABB_Item5
AABB_Item6
```

instead of:

```
AABB_Item1Item2Item3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(IF(INICIO!C4=AUX!Q2, AUX!Q3:Q10, )), 
             "AABB_"&IF(INICIO!C4=AUX!Q2, AUX!Q3:Q10, ), ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(INICIO!C4=AUX!Q2, P2&"_"&AUX!Q3:Q10), 
    "limit "&COUNTA(IF(INICIO!C4=AUX!Q2, AUX!Q3:Q10))))
```

[image: 0]